# iPhone timeIntervalSinceDate not throwing error, or working

Tags: iphone, datetime, nstimeinterval

I'm trying to find the difference between two NSDates.  This worked once and printed the difference, but has never worked again.  I don't remember changing any thing after the one time it worked.  Any ideas?  Oh, and it doesn't throw an error, and if I comment out this snippet everything works.

```
    //----------- Touches Begin
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    touchBegins = [NSDate date];
    NSLog (@"       Tap: %d ", tapTotal);
    NSLog (@"<=========================>");
    NSLog (@"Method: touchesBegines & Ends");
    NSLog (@"   Touch Begin: %@", touchBegins);
    // [self updateLabelsFromTouches:touches];
}


//----------- Touches End
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    touchEnds = [NSDate date];
    NSLog (@"   Touch Ends : %@", touchEnds );
    @try {
        NSLog(@"%@", touchEnds);
        NSTimeInterval elapsed = [touchEnds timeIntervalSinceDate:touchBegins];
    NSLog (@"   Finger Down:  %f", elapsed);
    } @catch (NSException *ex) {}

    NSLog (@" ");

    [self updateLabelsFromTouches:touches];
}
```

Console:

```
  [Session started at 2010-10-27 10:27:18 -0400.]
       Tap: 0 
 <=========================>
 Method: touchesBegines & Ends
 Touch Begin: 2010-10-27 14:27:22 GMT
 Touch Ends : 2010-10-27 14:27:22 GMT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Looking at the extra code you have added, you're not retaining touchBegins. Try this :

```
[[NSDate date] retain];
```

I'm surprised it's not just crashing when you call timeIntervalSinceDate :) - in fact, it is but you're catching the exception and then ignoring it!

You should add some exception logging in your @catch; just this should do it :

```
} @catch (NSException *ex) {
    NSLog(@"Exception getting time interval : %@", ex);
}
```

You might see a log message that says something like 'unrecognized selector' - you'll certainly see something interesting I'll bet!

---

Have a look at this : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

%d is an integer - try %f :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out the link.  %f didn't seem to help, but it's a step in the right direction :)

Comment: Are you 100% sure that touchEnds is not nil? Try adding `NSLog(@"%@", touchEnds);` in there as well

Comment: yeah, it's not nil, it gets set a few lines above that.  I added more of the code and a console read out up above on the question.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: you're not retaining touchBegins - try this : `[[NSDate date] retain]`